# Amchart 4 Legend In Arabic not Showing Properly

Tags: alignment, legend, pie-chart, amcharts4, legend-properties

[image]

I want To start the Legend marker from the right side I already used these three Properties.

chart.legend.reverseOrder = true;
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.reverseOrder = true;chart.rtl = true;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.reverseOrder = true;
chart.legend.position = "bottom";
chart.legend.valueLabels.template.align = "right";
chart.legend.valueLabels.template.textAlign = "right";
chart.legend.valueLabels.template.textDecoration = "rtl";
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**